# Body keeps overlapping in slider. How to fix this

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been messing with getting this Hulu clone slider to work, however I've come across this issue where the activated body is overlapped with the previous bodies that were open. I've tried to mess with the CSS and JS, but I haven't been able to find the answer to it.

```js
//Code to change the BG
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("styled-button");
//Added Code
let tabs = document.querySelector(".tabs");
let tabHeader = tabs.querySelector(".tab-header");
let tabBody = tabs.querySelector(".tab-body");
let tabIndicator = tabs.querySelector(".tab-indicator");
let tabHeaderNodes = tabs.querySelectorAll(".tab-header > div");
let tabBodyNodes = tabs.querySelectorAll(".tab-body > div");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  // console.log(els[i].id);
  els[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    changeBackground(this.id);
  });
}



for(let i=0;i<tabHeaderNodes.length;i++){
  tabHeaderNodes[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    tabHeader.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    tabHeaderNodes[i].classList.add("active");
    tabBody.querySelector(".active").classList.remove(".active");
    tabBodyNodes[i].classList.add("active");

    
    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 3) * ${i})`
  });

}




function changeBackground(id) {
  // document.querySelectorAll('[id^="background"]');
  // var classes = console.log(document.querySelector("body").classList.length);
  // clear all background classes from body
  const cls = [
    "background-image-books",
    "background-image-strawberries",
    "background-image-sea"
  ];
  document.querySelector("body").classList.remove(...cls);

  switch (id) {
    case "books":
      document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-image-books");
      break;
    case "strawberries":
      document
        .querySelector("body")
        .classList.add("background-image-strawberries");
      break;
    case "sea":
      document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-image-sea");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("switch caught nothing");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://sportsnaut.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Hulu-Sports2_Hulu-1-1024x544.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/* .styled-button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em auto auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #404040;
} */
.styled-button:active {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
p {
  color:white;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.preload-images {
  background-image: url(https://sportsnaut.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Hulu-Sports2_Hulu-1-1024x544.jpeg),
    url(https://www.hulu.com/static/hitch/s3/attachments/ckzyp4x986iio1k7rkj43368r-ckuh9mwg007ws1v4zm8i4kk07-ckqiozsqemxsf1u3mw3ihh0ti-news-1600x850-2x-full.jpg),
    url("https://picsum.photos/id/1053/960/540");
}
.background-image-books {
  background-color: #d2c2b5;
  background-image: url(https://sportsnaut.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Hulu-Sports2_Hulu-1-1024x544.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.background-image-strawberries {
  background-color: #d62752;
  background-image: url(https://www.hulu.com/static/hitch/s3/attachments/ckzyp4x986iio1k7rkj43368r-ckuh9mwg007ws1v4zm8i4kk07-ckqiozsqemxsf1u3mw3ihh0ti-news-1600x850-2x-full.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.background-image-sea {
  background-color: #56826b;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1053/960/540");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* Added Code */
.tabs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  /* background: #f5f5f5; */
  padding: 20px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.tabs .tab-header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
}

.tabs .tab-header > div {
  width: calc(90% / 3);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(160, 159, 159);
  text-align-last: left;
}

.tabs .tab-header > div.active {
  color: white;
}

.tabs .tab-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(55% / 3);
  height: 6px;
  background: white;
  justify-self: center;
  /*left: 0px;*/
  margin-top: -25px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

/* .styled-button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em auto auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #404040;
} 
*/ 
.tab-body {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.tabs .tab-body > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms,
     transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.tabs .tab-body > div.active {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="preload-images"></div> <!-- for image preloading -->
  <div class="tabs">
 <div class="tab-header">
  <div class="styled-button active" id="books">
    <p>LIVE SPORTS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-button" id="strawberries">
    <p>BREAKING NEWS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-button" id="sea">
    <p>BIG EVENTS</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    
      <div class = "tab-indicator"></div>
    
    <div class="tab-body" id="sports">
<div class="active">
  <div>
    <h2>Live Sports</h2>
    <p>Catch your games at home or on the go. Stream live games from major college and pro leagues including the NCAA®, NBA, NHL, NFL, and more.</p>
    <div class="live-sports-logos">
      <div>
          <img src="/img/live-sports-logo-1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/live-sports-logo-2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/live-sports-logo-3.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/live-sports-logo-4.png" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div id = "news">
    <h2>Breaking News</h2>
    <p>Keep pace with what's going on locally and globally with trusted opinions from all the top news networks.</p>
    <div class="breaking-news-logos">
      <div>
          <img src="/img/breaking-news/abc-news-live.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/breaking-news/cnn-logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/breaking-news/msnb-logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="/img/breaking-news/fox-news.png" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id = "events">
    <h2>Biggest Events</h2>
    <p>Spectacular, can't-miss moments like the Olympics, Grammys®, Oscars®, Emmys®, and more.</p>
      <div class="big-events-logos">
        <div>
            <img src="/img/biggest-events/emmy-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/biggest-events/gga-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/biggest-events/grammy-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/biggest-events/oscar_logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons need to have some kind of "target identifier", something like `data-target-id="news"`.

Then you give to your "background sections" the corresponding id, for instance `id="news="`.

Then on your `changeBackgrounds` function you have to loop through all possible background sections. If the section id matches the `data-target-id` of the clicked button, then you show the section, if not, you hide it...

Take a look at the example i made you. It is just a simple version, but i think you get what i mean...

```js
// Get all elements
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let selectedSection = 'one';

// Add click listeners to all buttons
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // update the selected section value
        selectedSection = event.target.getAttribute('data-target-id');
        // update the visible sections
        updateVisibleSections();
    })
});

// Show the section that matches the "visibleSection" variable and hide all other sections
function updateVisibleSections() {
    sections.forEach((section) => {
        if (section.id === selectedSection) {
            section.classList.add('visible');
        } else {
            section.classList.remove('visible')
        }
    })
}

// update visible sections when page loads
updateVisibleSections();
```

```css
section {
    display: none;
}

section.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button data-target-id="one">one</button>
<button data-target-id="two">two</button>
<button data-target-id="three">three</button>

<section id="one">
    <h1>Section one</h1>
</section>
<section id="two">
    <h1>Section two</h1>
</section>
<section id="three">
    <h1>Section three</h1>
</section>
```